# How to remove a column and increase count of rows based on the value of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm relatively new to R. I have a data frame with 939 rows that looks like this:

| cuisine | Number.of.order | Customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fastfood | 2 | 1 |
| cakes | 3 | 1 |
| Western | 4 | 2 |
| Chinese | 5 | 3 |

What i want is to get rid of the Numbers.of.order column and add the values inside the column as addition rows.

Something like this:

| cuisine | Customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| Fastfood | 1 |
| Fastfood | 1 |
| cakes | 1 |
| cakes | 1 |
| cakes | 1 |
| Western | 2 |
| Western | 2 |
| Western | 2 |
| Western | 2 |
| Chinese | 3 |
| Chinese | 3 |
| Chinese | 3 |
| Chinese | 3 |
| Chinese | 3 |

Im doing this so that I can convert it into a transaction dataframe for association rules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    uncount(Number.of.order)

    cuisine Customer_id
1  Fastfood           1
2  Fastfood           1
3     cakes           1
4     cakes           1
5     cakes           1
6   Western           2
7   Western           2
8   Western           2
9   Western           2
10  Chinese           3
11  Chinese           3
12  Chinese           3
13  Chinese           3
14  Chinese           3
```

Answer (score 2):

An option in `base R` with `rep`

```
out <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Number.of.order), -2]
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
out
    cuisine Customer_id
1  Fastfood           1
2  Fastfood           1
3     cakes           1
4     cakes           1
5     cakes           1
6   Western           2
7   Western           2
8   Western           2
9   Western           2
10  Chinese           3
11  Chinese           3
12  Chinese           3
13  Chinese           3
14  Chinese           3
```